# Objective c Twitter Api : which to use?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, twitter

In the twitter's developer page mentioned three twitter engine for objective c:

MGTwitterEngine, Canary ,ShareKit.

Which is the best?
Is there another possibility?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used MGTwitterEngine, and I've started to roll my own, since I'd like to use the streaming API and it doesn't have support for it. I like mine the best, but MGTwitterEngine is very easy to use. ShareKit I didn't much like when I gave it a go a few months back (adding Instapaper support to an app, ended up just writing my own Instapaper stuff too). I've never used Canary.

Objectively just talking about MGTwitterEngine and ShareKit, you'll be faster up and running with ShareKit, but you may not like using it long term.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I'll start with MG then.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All depends on what your needs.

MGTwitterEngine is mainly made for OS X / iPhone twitter applications

Canary focuses on multiple timelines, filtering and drag-n-drop functions

ShareKit isn't a Twitter specific kit but a social kit for multiple social platforms

Comment: ok.. so MGtwitterEngine seems to be the way to start.. I've downloaded the code, but it doesn't compile, it seems to be a large amount of classes missing.. so I see it usees oAuth: then I've downloaded the OAuth libraries and added it to the project.. now something called yajl seems to be missing, but I can't find what it is.. do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: You still need OAuthConsumer, it's a separate library.

Answer (score 0):

You can try www.pinkelstar.com. Works out of the box for both iOS and Android.

Comment: Hey.. thanks! looks great. I've been reading some about this and maybe I'm wrong, but pinkle api let you integrate your app with some services of a product (twitter, facebook, etc), but do not support all services and It's not designed for being a service core for an application.. What's your opinion? Thanks again